# cassandra query (cql3) slow on 200GB table

Tags: cassandra, stress-testing, cql3

I've created a stress test for cassandra using 1 table which contains a lot of data. I've populated a table with 200GB data, each row been around 4k on average. The primary key is a long and there are no extra indexes. And now I am running a query stress test. So I have 16 threads querying cassandra with a where class on the primary key. I was expecting this to be fast, but I am getting 600ms on avg query time and 2.5 secs max time per thread.

As said the query is something like select * from table where id=?

What could be wrong?

edit: some more details about my setup. I run locally on my box a cassandra cluster with two lxc-based virtual boxes. lxc-io should be fairly efficient if not in pair as native io. And I didn't have any issue when I was populating the cluster with the data. Now I am running queries only, in 16 threads on my 16-core box. All queries go to cassandra1. The block size of the disk is 4kb.

I am currently compacting and will see if that helps.

edit: table:

```
CREATE TABLE session (
  id bigint PRIMARY KEY,
  data blob,
  ip text,
  site text,
  time timestamp,
  txt text,
  useragent text
) WITH
  bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.010000 AND
  caching='KEYS_ONLY' AND
  comment='' AND
  dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.000000 AND
  gc_grace_seconds=864000 AND
  read_repair_chance=0.100000 AND
  replicate_on_write='true' AND
  compaction={'class': 'SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'} AND
  compression={'sstable_compression': 'SnappyCompressor'};
```

Note: data column is null

Comment: The response time is abnormal, you should post more information. Check http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/how-not-to-benchmark-cassandra for more info.

Comment: There are a few things that might affect it: 1. I am running a cluster of 2 cassandras on lxc on the same box. But after I inserted the data, I am only querying cassandra1 for the data and cassandra2 is idle.  2. As said, I am using lxc, but that shouldn't affect performance, i.e. the writes were done in good time.  3. The block size of my ext4 FS is 4k. Looks ok to me or not?

Comment: Can you share your `CREATE TABLE`? It might help to see your table design, as this can affect query performance.

Comment: Also, the long key may be an issue. It will affect how many keys can be stored in your key cache.

Comment: I've added the ddl for the table. Also I am not requesting the same key twice when I run the stress test. For each query, the id clause is always different.

Comment: Take a look at the tracing for you query. http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/tracing_r.html

Comment: After compaction, dt per query dropped to 240ms on average, 1800ms max. Still bit slow. I'll try to trace the queries.